# Cant get JSFiddle to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I added the code below to the top of my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwtD9/1/) and It stopped working, I would think its a simple fix but I can't figure it out:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);

// assign the correct target
var target = $('#if_two');

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200, function(){
    target.css({'border-color': 'red'})
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). You're using the variable `target` before you've assigned a value to it.

Comment: You're getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'offset' of undefined`. This means `target` is undefined. Put this code in `document.ready`.

Comment: Check the console: `Cannot call method 'offset' of undefined`

Comment: @FritsvanCampen jsfiddle already wraps it to a document ready event.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? What do you mean by "added the code below to the top of my JSFiddle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was just the ordering of your code. When the code gets evaluated it actually works more like this

```
var target;

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);

// assign the correct target
target = $('#if_two');

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200, function(){
    target.css({'border-color': 'red'})
});
```

This process is called variable hoisting. So when

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);
```

executes, `target` is still undefined. If you order your code in the following way it works.

```
// assign the correct target
var target = $('#if_two');

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200, function(){
    target.css({'border-color': 'red'})
});
```

Here the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TomLee/TwtD9/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are using target before it's defined.  See here for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TwtD9/4/

```
// assign the correct target
var target = $('#if_two');

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200, function(){
    target.css({'border-color': 'red'})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All the commenters and the answer are of course right, but do you know of the developer console (f12 in most browsers)? because if you open that console, you will see the error, as mentioned:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'offset' of undefined'
```